# Y axis not showing when graphing large x-values

Tags: plotting

When I run `ParametricPlot[{g, r}, {x, 0, 250000000}]`, where the output values for function `r` are expected to always be extremely small ($< 100$), I get the following graph, where the values are stuck on the x-axis and not scaled appropriately. I am struggling to understand why.

[image: error graph]

The same equations used for smaller $t$ values (`ParametricPlot[{g, r}, {x, 0, 100}]`), gives a graph much more like I am expecting.

[image: good graph]

I am new to Mathematica, so sorry if this is a trivial question. Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Try using `ParametricPlot[{g,r},{x,0,250000000},AspectRatio->1]`.

Comment: @Graumagier That works. If you'd like to make it an answer, I can mark as correct to help future visitors